# C# Rally RestAPI Add or Update A Tag

Tags: c#, json, tags, rally

I cannot find the syntax to add a tag value to a User Story via C#.

Using the latest Rally API binaries, 2.0 Beta.

Closest example I can find is via Java ( [How to add Tags to a TestCase in Rally using Rally's JAVA API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655357/how-to-add-tags-to-a-testcase-in-rally-using-rallys-java-api) ), which looks helpful, but from the example I'll need access to JSONArray and JSONElement but my C# Deployment uses `DynamicJSONObject` via the RestAPI as per the Rally examples, but neither `JSONArray` nor `DynamicJSONArray` (nor also `JSONElement`) are exposed via the RestAPI Reference.

I Could enable `DynamicJSONArray` access by adding Microsoft's `System.Web.Helpers` reference, but the Microsoft `DynamicJSonArray` reference contends with the RestAPI variant...

I Could use the full name to qualify the restapi variants to get around this but I don't really want to start down this road with no clear view if it will lead to something functional.If I pass a Microsoft `DyamicJSONArray` into the Rally `DyamicJSONObject`, I'm dubious anything functional will come of it.

Does anyone have any C# Code doing something as simple as creating a tag and assiging it to a user story or test case?

Comment: "_Does anyone have any C# Code doing something.._" This is not a good way to ask on Stackoverflow. Did you tried anything so far? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example that updates the Tag Collection on a Story both with an Existing Tag and a newly-created Tag:

```
namespace RestExample_UpdateStoryTags
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi;
            String rallyUserName = "user@company.com";
            String rallyPassword = "topsecret";
            String rallyURL = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String wsapiVersion = "1.41";
            String myWorkspaceName = "My Workspace";

            restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                rallyUserName,
                rallyPassword,
                rallyURL,
                wsapiVersion
            );

            // Get a Reference to Target Workspace
            Request workspaceRequest = new Request("workspace");
            workspaceRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "ObjectID"
                };

            workspaceRequest.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, myWorkspaceName);
            QueryResult workspaceQueryResults = restApi.Query(workspaceRequest);

            var targetWorkspace = workspaceQueryResults.Results.First();
            Console.WriteLine("Found Target Workspace: " + targetWorkspace["Name"]);

            String workspaceRef = targetWorkspace["_ref"];

            //Query for Target Tag
            Request tagRequest = new Request("tag");
            tagRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "ObjectID"
                };

            // Query all Tags for a tag named "Montane"
            tagRequest.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "Tundra");
            QueryResult queryTagResults = restApi.Query(tagRequest);

            var targetTagResult = queryTagResults.Results.First();
            long tagOID = targetTagResult["ObjectID"];

            DynamicJsonObject targetTag = restApi.GetByReference("tag", tagOID, "Name", "ObjectID");

            // Query for User Story
            // FormattedID of target story
            String targetStoryFormattedID = "US5";

            Request storyRequest = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
            storyRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "ObjectID",
                    "Iteration",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "Tags"
            };


            storyRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, targetStoryFormattedID);
            QueryResult queryStoryResults = restApi.Query(storyRequest);

            var targetUserStory = queryStoryResults.Results.First();
            Console.WriteLine("Found Target User Story: " + targetUserStory["Name"]);

            // Grab collection of existing Tags
            var existingTags = targetUserStory["Tags"];

            // Summarize Existing Tags
            Console.WriteLine("Existing Tags for Story" + targetStoryFormattedID + ": ");
            foreach (var tag in existingTags)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tag["Name"]);
            }

            long targetOID = targetUserStory["ObjectID"];

            // Now do update of the User Story

            // Tags collection on object is expected to be a System.Collections.ArrayList
            var targetTagArray = existingTags;
            targetTagArray.Add(targetTag);

            DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
            toUpdate["Tags"] = targetTagArray;

            OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update("HierarchicalRequirement", targetOID, toUpdate);
            foreach (var error in updateResult.Errors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
            }

            // Re-read target Story
            DynamicJsonObject updatedStory = restApi.GetByReference(targetUserStory["_ref"], "Tags,Name");
            var updatedTags = updatedStory["Tags"];

            // Summarize Updated Tags
            Console.WriteLine("Updated Tags for Story" + targetStoryFormattedID + ": ");
            foreach (var tag in updatedTags)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tag["Name"]);
            }

            // Create a New Tag, and add New Tag to Story
            DynamicJsonObject newTag = new DynamicJsonObject();
            newTag["Name"] = "Boreal";

            CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "Tag", newTag);

            // Get the ref of the created Tag
            String newTagRef = createResult.Reference;

            // Read the Target Tag
            DynamicJsonObject newTagRead = restApi.GetByReference(newTagRef, "Name");

            // Add the newly-created Tag to the Story
            targetTagArray.Add(newTagRead);
            toUpdate["Tags"] = targetTagArray;

            updateResult = restApi.Update("HierarchicalRequirement", targetOID, toUpdate);

            // Re-read target Story
            updatedStory = restApi.GetByReference(targetUserStory["_ref"], "Tags,Name");
            updatedTags = updatedStory["Tags"];

            // Summarize Updated Tags
            Console.WriteLine("Updated Tags (with newly-created Tag for Story" + targetStoryFormattedID + ": ");
            foreach (var tag in updatedTags)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tag["Name"]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark, many thanks for your post. It has certainly moved me closer, but but a few issues Remain. Perhaps my issues are around use of the 2.0 beta API...
First, I had to tweak the syntax to get access to the array collection...
var tagList = existingTags["_tagsNameArray"];
tagsNameArray give me access to the collection you specify, so I can read and iterate the data. But, if I

Comment: Mark, many thanks for your post. It has certainly moved me closer, but a few issues remain. Perhaps my issues are around use of the 2.0 beta API... First, I had to tweak the syntax to get access to the array collection... var tagList = existingTags["_tagsNameArray"]; tagsNameArray gives me access to the collection you specify, so I can read and iterate the data. I can append to this list, but when I try to update it I get an error... "Could not read: Could not read referenced object 2". I get this error even if a reassign the original array unchanged (without adding any tags to it). Will post.

Comment: Hmmm space pretty limited. I guess i'll include the context in an answer to this question.

Comment: The .NET REST toolkit hasn't been updated or tested against WSAPI 2.0. It would be best to use 1.41.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Based on Mark's code, below comes close... but updates still failing
//Maybe I need to try an earlier version?

String strTeam = "xxx";

String workspaceRef = "/workspace/4914063320";
String projectRef = "/project/7412041414";

//get user story
Request reqUserStory = new Request("hierarchicalrequirement");
reqUserStory.Fetch = new List<string>() { "ObjectID", "Release", "Iteration", "PlanEstimate", "Description", "Tags" };

reqUserStory.Query = new Query("Project", Query.Operator.Equals, projectRef)
    .And(new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "mystoryname"));

QueryResult queryResultUS = restApi.Query(reqUserStory);
DynamicJsonObject myUserStory = new DynamicJsonObject();
myUserStory = queryResultUS.Results.FirstOrDefault();
if (null != myUserStory)
{
//get tags for user story
    var existingTags = myUserStory["Tags"];
    if (null != existingTags)
    {
        bool bFound = false;

        var tagList = existingTags["_tagsNameArray"];
        //look for tag
        foreach (var tag in tagList)
        {
            String strValue = tag["Name"];
            if (strValue == strTeam)
                bFound = true;
        }

        if (!bFound)
        {
            //replace tags array

            var targetTagArray = existingTags;
            var tagList2 = targetTagArray["_tagsNameArray"];
            tagList2.Add(targetTag);//even if i comment this out, update below fails...
            targetTagArray["_tagsNameArray"] = tagList2;

            DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
            toUpdate["Tags"] = targetTagArray;
            long oid = Convert.ToInt64(myUserStory["ObjectID"]);
            opResultRelease = restApi.Update("hierarchicalrequirement", oid, toUpdate);
            // Fails with Error: ["Could not read: Could not read referenced object 2"]
        }

    }
}
```